# Appolonius circle with $\infty$ as one limit point.

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, geometry

For two complex numbers $a,b$ circle of appollonius with limit point $a$ and $b$ are given by $$\left\lvert \frac{z-a}{z-b}\right\rvert=r.$$ I can only see these circles when limit points are finite numbers. I do not know what is the equation of this circle when one of the limit point is $\infty$. I read it somewhere that the appolonius circle with limit $0$ and $\infty$ are concentric cirlcles.  Can anyone help me understanding this statement?

Comment: A circle that goes through infinity sounds like a line to me.

Comment: @JanDvorak in question, circle with LIMIT POINT $\infty$ is considered, not passing through $\infty$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Projective formulation

One way to properly handle infinity is to go into projective geometry, namely the projective complex line $\mathbb{CP}^1$ by introducing homogeneous coordinates

$$Z=\begin{pmatrix}z\\1\end{pmatrix}\qquad
A=\begin{pmatrix}a\\1\end{pmatrix}\qquad
B=\begin{pmatrix}b\\1\end{pmatrix}\qquad
\infty=\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}$$

Then you can write the circle equation as a cross ratio, which does no longer depend on representatives:

$$\left|\operatorname{CR}(Z,\infty;A,B)\right|=
\left|\frac{[Z,A][\infty,B]}{[Z,B][\infty,A]}\right|=
\left|\frac
{\begin{vmatrix}z&a\\1&1\end{vmatrix}\cdot
\begin{vmatrix}1&b\\0&1\end{vmatrix}}
{\begin{vmatrix}z&b\\1&1\end{vmatrix}\cdot
\begin{vmatrix}1&a\\0&1\end{vmatrix}}\right|
=\left|\frac{z-a}{z-b}\right|=r$$

But this does not really solve the problem, since if you set $A=\infty$ or $B=\infty$ then the cross ratio will become $\infty$ resp. $0$ no matter the value of $Z$ (except for some special locations where it will be undefined).

## Circle through point

So let's try something different. Let's try to get rid of the $\infty$ in the cross ratio, and also of this $r$ which becomes ill-defined for that case. Instead of describing the circle by its ratio $r$, one might as well describe the circle by another point $P$ through which it passes. For the finite case, every $P$ corresponds to one $r$, and for every $r$ you'll find some $P$, so you don't loose any circles. With this formulation, you get

\begin{align*}
\left|\operatorname{CR}(Z,\infty;A,B)\right| &=
\left|\operatorname{CR}(P,\infty;A,B)\right| = r \\
\operatorname{CR}(Z,\infty;A,B) &=
e^{i\varphi}\operatorname{CR}(P,\infty;A,B) \\
\frac{[Z,A][\infty,B]}{[Z,B][\infty,A]} &=
e^{i\varphi}\frac{[P,A][\infty,B]}{[P,B][\infty,A]} \\
[Z,A][P,B] &= e^{i\varphi}[P,A][Z,B] \\
\operatorname{CR}(Z,P;A,B) &= e^{i\varphi} \\
\left|\operatorname{CR}(Z,P;A,B)\right| &= 1 \\
\left|\frac{(z-a)(p-b)}{(z-b)(p-a)}\right| &= 1
\end{align*}

## Case at infinity

Now this formulation can be used to set e.g. $B=\infty$. In that case you get

\begin{align*}
1&=\left|\operatorname{CR}(Z,P;A,\infty)\right|=\left|\frac{z-a}{p-a}\right|\\
\lvert z-a\rvert &=\lvert p-a\rvert
\end{align*}

This is obviously the equation of a circle around $a$ going through $p$. So if you don't fix $p$, then the whole family of such circles would be a family of concentric circles around $a$.

Comment: I am not that much familiar with projective spaces, is there any other way to see this?

Comment: @user1123: The last equation of my second section, i.e. $$\left|\frac{(z-a)(p-b)}{(z-b)(p-a)}\right|=1$$ could be deduced from your equation and $r/r=1$ as well. If you use that, then in the last section one could use a limit process instead of the homogeneous coordinates I used. $$\lim_{b\to\infty}\frac{p-b}{z-b}=1$$